# Do I need to reindex my table in mysql after delete?

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, performance-tuning

I have a table in mysql with a lot of INSERT and SELECT at every second. And there is a bulk delete of some older data once in a day. Do I need to reindex the table after delete? I want to increase the performance. Can anybody suggest some tips? Using 'innodb' as engine. Do I need to change it? I think its better for concurrent insert and select. pls give your suggestions. Do I need reindexing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you meant _optimize_ for which the best is to read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Further to this you could consider partitioning for simple archiving strategy.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a lot on insert and delete operations on a table, the table will be "fragmented", and the statistics that are used to decide the execution plan of a query will not be accurate. So YES, it is recommended to optimize the table from time to time (Not necessarily after each delete, but when a significant changes happen)
hth

Comment: The main aim is to speed up SELECT query. There is insertion to table at every seconds. Does the Optimize will speed up my select query?

Comment: Yes, OPTIMIZE will improve the speed in two ways: 
1- It will defragment the table, so less disk access is required
2- It will make sure the execution plan is the good one, because it is based on the stats that are updated after the optimization.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no update and you are deleting old data, you might think of creating daily tables with date on its name. You can create a view to query them and you can easily drop the old table.

Comment: Suggestions in comments area please.